# running python code on sublime and atom error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
for i in range(500): # this "for" loop will repeat these functions 500 times
    forward(i)
    left(91)
```

I want to run python code including usage of "turtle" class ,I tried to use sublime text editor after installing python environment from here : https://www.python.org/downloads/

it gives me that error

Atom:

[image]

Sublime:

[image]

I have installed atom-runner package and turtle package and still the error !

Comment: Please post your code and all relevant information (complete tracebacks, etc) as **text**, not as images.

Comment: sublime :
from turtle import *
for i in range(500): # this "for" loop will repeat these functions 500 times
    forward(i)
    left(91)
error:
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.14 seconds]

Comment: atom:
import turtle
from turtle import *

for i in range(500): # this "for" loop will repeat these functions 500 times
    forward(i)
    left(91)
error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.23.3\python\turtle\turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.23.3\python\turtle\turtle.py", line 5, in <module>
    forward(i)
NameError: name 'forward' is not defined
[Finished in 0.456s]

Comment: @Salwa Don't post code in the comments, please edit your question.

Comment: @Simon that is the problem it does not work on mine!

Comment: Please keep that format for for HTML CSS JavaScript only.  Edit with four spaces

Comment: You have two separate problems. The first is that you named you file `turtle.py` but `turtle` is the name of the library you are using, causing you to import the file itself, which hasn't defined `forward`... Hence the error. The other seems to be some error in the way Sublime is configured.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is define what you want to move forward and turn. When you are using a module you first import it then use it's functions with the lines:

```
module_name.function(variables)
```

so you have to edit your code to make it look like this:

```
import turtle
for i in range(500):
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.left(91)
```

or

```
import turtle as t
```

and replace

> 'turtle'

with

> 't'

Comment: Although it is certainly better practice to use what you put

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code but the file.

You are importing your own file.  You have imported `turtle.py` and the name of your file is `turtle.py`.

Never name your `.py` file the same as  a module.  Rename your file to a name that is not a module in your standard library.

The problem in sublime in sublime is that you have not have not configured it to run Python files correctly.

Comment: I thought that was the problem as well, but I tried it myself, and somehow it works

Comment: @ViG  I am confused.  Do you mean to say it does not work

Comment: I mean that I've created a file named `turtle.py`, with OP's code, and it runs without any problem.

Comment: @ViG  Could I ask you to double check that.  I just ran this and I am definitely getting a `NameError: name 'forward' is not defined`  If not this is a most curious problem

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. Before this question I ran a file that imported `turtle`, and I guess it was still in my cache when I ran `turtle.py` with OP's code. I restarted my IDE and then I also got the error, when I ran the `turtle.py`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ViG  No problem everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: @Salwa  Great! You can also [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for future visitors with the problem, so they know where to look as well. If you want. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you are mostly good to go.

#1 always import turtle. [Looks good]
Code: import turtle

#2 Write out your handle.[Looks good]
Code: jojo = turtle.Turtle()

#3 Completion of your turtle should be closed properly, otherwise your program will close
on yourself. [I think this was missing.]

code: turtle.done()

example: This should work (atom editor)

```
import turtle
jojo = turtle.Turtle()
jojo.color("red")
jojo.pensize(5)
jojo.shape("turtle")
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

example: This will close on itself (atom editor)

```
import turtle
jojo = turtle.Turtle()
jojo.color("red")
jojo.pensize(5)
jojo.shape("turtle")
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
jojo.left(90)
jojo.forward(100)
#turtle.done()
```